# Putting in size requirement function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit new to the JavaScript side of things.

I am trying to include a conditional statement in my code so that it only works on screen sizes above 768px

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
            $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
      } 
      else {
           $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
      }
});
```

and include

```
if ($(window).width() > 768)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very detailed, I'm guessing you want to execute part of your function on the given condition.

You should try:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
 if ($(window).width() > 768)
 {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) 
     {
        $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg- 
        fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
     } 
     else 
     {
        $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg- 
        fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
     }
 } 
 });
```

Also, $(document).width() is different from $(window).width(). Might want to try that too. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add your condition before checking the `scrollTop` like below.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
   if($(window).width() > 768) {    
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
        $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill black').removeClass('white');
      } else {
         $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill black').addClass('white');
      }
   }   
});
```

The above code will work only when the window width is > 768. You can check it out the same in the below snippet. I just applied some background color green when the `scrollTop > 70` and window width > 768. Also you can add/remove the multiple class in one short, no need to use `add/removeClass` everytime. Here is the [**Fiddle Version.**](https://jsfiddle.net/58p2fjcs/19/)

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if($(window).width() > 768) {    
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
      $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill black').removeClass('white');
    } else {
      $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill black').addClass('white');
    }
 }   
});
```

```css
.bg-fill {
  background:green;
}
.white {
  color:black;
}
.black {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anim-nav">
<p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p><p>
This is the test paragraph
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking at working with a screen width, the simplest solution is to use `window.matchMedia`:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
    alert('wide');
} else {
    alert('narrow');
}
```

It works on all modern browsers as well as IE>=10.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia for more information.